# How to get text of element without tags from the DOM

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]

I'm using

```
self.driver.find_element("//table//tr//td//b[contains(.,'Description')]//following-sibling::text()[1]").text
```

also tried

```
self.driver.find_element("//table//tr//td//b[contains(.,'Description')]//following-sibling::text()[1]").get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text()` in the `xoath` returns text node, however Selenium doesn't support it. The text is part of the `<td>` tag, you can use the child `<input>` to locate it

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="libdet_edit"]/..').text
```

If you don't want the `"description"` you can locate the `<b>` tag and remove its text

```
td = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="libdet_edit"]/..')
all_text = td.text
b_text = td.find_element_by_xpath(".//b").text
text = all_text.replace(b_text, '')
```

Comment: Thanks Guy, Your opinion worked, I have just put


all_text = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="libdet_edit"]/..').text
all_text  = all_text.replace.replace("Description:", '')